# Rstudio not reading in file

Tags: r

I'm trying to read a csv file into Rstudio on a Mac.

```
1) getwd() -> /Test
2) list.files() -> shows CitesforSarah.csv
3) papers <- as_tibble(read_csv("/Test/CitesforSarah.csv")  -> file not found
```

How do we read in this file?  the package tidyverse is installed and loaded

Comment: Try `read_csv("CitesforSarah.csv")`

Comment: If "/Test" is your current working directory, then you should not include it in your path to `read_csv` (unless there's another folder called "Test" inside that "Test" folder)